# Error in incrementing a element in LPSTR (UNICODE) C++

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I am currently checking the appropriate spacing of chars in Windows application..
  but i wanted to test it out so i made this code snippet but it throw up an exception and it only throws it when i increment r[0].

but from my understanding r stores "A\0".r[0] will de-reference 'r[0]' which will increment Right?Am i wrong if so help me.

i have used static because r is in WM_PAINT message.

```
//function starts
.
.
. 

static LPTSTR r = TEXT("A");
TextOut(hdc, x, y + cy + cy + cspace + cspace, r,   sizeof(r));
TextOut(hdc, x+tm.tmAveCharWidth*1.5, y + cy + cy + cspace + cspace, r, sizeof(r));

if (r[0]<93)
r[0]++;

.
.
.
```

Comment: Do you have all warnings enabled and are paying attention too? That should make it clear why what you did is bad.

Comment: there are no warnings .. just This Error In VS:                   First-chance exception at 0x011C5271 in Windows.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x011D1B7C.
Unhandled exception at 0x011C5271 in Windows.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callb

Comment: I'm sure the Microsoft Compiler will flag your code, if you ask for all warnings: `-Wall`. Anyway, running the program comes later than that.

Comment: "r" is a pointer to a string literal (also called a string constant), but you are trying to increment the first character in the string literal. It looks like the string literal is being stored in memory that you don't have write access to. To check this out try this simplified version of your code:

static LPTSTR r = TEXT("A");
r[0]++;

If you still get an access violation then clearly you can't write to the memory that the string literal is stored in. If you really want to do this then you may have to copy the literal into a buffer and write to that buffer.

Comment: Do not use LPTSTR and TEXT macro. They are no good. See http://utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
static LPTSTR r = TEXT("A");
```

to

```
static TCHAR r[2] = _T("A");
```

What you have is a pointer to a constant string. You can't change a constant. What you need to do is allocate memory that you can actually modify.

Answer (score 1):

Identified these points:

1. Using `TCHAR`: Please avoid them, they are only for porting ancient windows application. You aren't doing that, right?
2. `sizeof(r)` is `sizeof(LPTSTR)`, not the length of the string you want to pass. Use `strlen` or the wide variant.
3. r[0]++: r points to a string literal, which is constant, thus you have **undefined behavior**, anything may happen, in your case an "Access violation".

Comment: ok , i used lstrlen(r) but the exception is still present and... but about your 3rd point do yo know how to convert wchar_t * to LPWSTR.and thanks for pointing out the legacy but old habits die hard,right?.

Comment: The second is a typedef for the first. If you want to modify a string, make sure it is not a constant literal. Allocate some memory and copy it. You might alternatively use an auto/static array like this: `wchar_t text[]="Wonderful Text";`

Comment: i used this , static wchar_t r[] = L"A";  but the compiler gives this:Error 1 error C2664: 'int lstrlenA(LPCSTR)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'wchar_t [2]' to 'LPCSTR'  i also knew it would be an error as it tried it before.

Comment: `LPWSTR` is not `LPCSTR`. Please decide which you want, the standard library functions or the micosoft replacements, the `wchar_t` or the `char` ones.

Comment: anyway, LPWSTR din't also work But The Rob K's Solution Works like A charm!.

Comment: Well, i pointed out all that was wrong and why. Didn't know I should disregard all but the part you knew about an write your replacement code.